# Unable to load fontawesome icons in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I am attempting to add some icons to some food labels in shiny using the fontawesome icons. I see that the icons like "cheese" and "pizza-slice" are free to use yet when I try to load them nothing happens. I was able to find the .css files in the shiny directory and I searched for those icons and they are not there. Also at the top of the css file it shows version 5.3.1 so it appears I am using a newer version.

I have tried installing emojifont in rstudio. I have also tried installing fontawesome on the server with yum install fontawesome which it did download a package but no changes to the outcome. I also tried cycling the rstudio-server and shiny-server

menuItem("Lunch Menu", tabName = "lunch", icon = icon("cheese")),

There are no error messages and the icon does not show.

Comment: If you end up not being able to use `fontawesome`, here's a [great tutorial on styling Shiny apps](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) that includes using Google font APIs. I've used it on my own Shiny apps, and they've worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I think shiny only supports FontAwesome 4.7: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/

The icons supported have CSS class `fa`, rather than the newer `fas`.

EDIT: As of shiny 1.2.0, FontAwesome 5 is supported - perhaps you need to upgrade to a newer version?

---

**Edit**: Not to do with your shiny version then :) see similar answer here: [How to use the icons of the "fas" "far" "fal" "fab" type from fontawesome in shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671233/how-to-use-the-icons-of-the-fas-far-fal-fab-type-from-fontawesome-in-shi/56671514#56671514)

Looks like there's a pre-defined list of the icons available from FA 5, which get prefixed with "fab" - otherwise you're stuck with icons of class "fa" I'm afraid.

Comment: I am currently running shiny version 1.3.2