# How to use the icons of the "fas" "far" "fal" "fab" type from fontawesome in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, icons, font-awesome

I can only user "fa" Style Prefix um `shiny::icon()` and which creates the code like `<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>`.

How to user the others Style Prefix of [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the icon you want is in the list here: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/font-awesome.R

then it will automatically change to use "fab" as the prefix - otherwise it will always use "fa" I think. The relevant code from inside `shiny::icon` is:

```r
if (!is.null(name)) {
        prefix_class <- prefix
        if (prefix_class == "fa" && name %in% font_awesome_brands) {
            prefix_class <- "fab"
        }
        iconClass <- paste0(prefix_class, " ", prefix, "-", name)
    }
```

Comment: Link provided 404s as of 5/17/2021. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this - as of [PR 3302](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/3302) shiny now uses the new [fontawesome](https://github.com/rstudio/fontawesome) package for serving icons, so this answer is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the prefix by creating the icon yourself

```
htmltools::browsable(tags$i(class = "far fa-user-circle"))
```

This can be passed in the icon argument of shiny ui elements

```
actionButton(..., icon = htmltools::browsable(tags$i(class = "far fa-user-circle")))
```